# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING when the request body is not read

Tags: django, nginx, safari, wsgi

The following is an account of my crusade against an interesting bug that though I've resolved, I don't understand. I found a *solution*, but I'm really hoping someone can provide some insight into the actual cause of the bug.

### Problem Background

This issue first surfaced on the production server of our Django app. The stack was as follows

- AngularJS
- nginx
- uWSGI
- Django
- PostgreSQL

Our team identified an issue with a single POST request on Safari. Safari would choke on the response and spit out an `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`. The post request was as follows:

```
class ContractCloseOutSubmitView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, contract_id):
        contract = get_object_or_404(
            ContractCloseOut, pk=contract_id)
        if contract.submit():
            return Response({"detail": "Closed successfully."}, status=200)
        else:
            raise ParseError("Could not submit.")
```

The request is a simple request to mark an object as *closed*. We use this pattern in many places in the site, so this issue obviously required attention.

### Solution

Our first clue was that the request *did* close the object. That is, the line `if contract.submit()` must have been reached. That narrows down the problem to the response. I did some reading and there is a wide range of causes for this error. We tried:

- Explicitly setting the content length in Django
- Some hacks that forced nginx to more reliable judge content length
- Rewriting the code a few different ways

Nothing worked, and the problem still never occurred locally. So we decided to replicate the entire stack locally and test. One at a time, we removed elements of the network layer and identified that removing nginx and talking directly to uWSGI solved the issue.

So now we are confident that the problem lies in nginx, but still have no solution. Well, somewhere deep into the third page of Google, I came across a StackOverflow post that had a short comment somewhere mentioning that **reading the request body** had some sort of impact on nginx's buffers and how it judges content length (this is stuff I'm not super familiar with). Anyway, apparently a solution to issues with this is to simply read the buffer. That is, to *use* the request body. So I tried simply touching the request body by assigning its value to a variable:

```
class ContractCloseOutSubmitView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, contract_id):

        data = request.data #touchie touchie

        contract = get_object_or_404(
            ContractCloseOut, pk=contract_id)
        if contract.submit():
            return Response({"detail": "Closed successfuly."}, status=200)
        else:
            raise ParseError("Could not submit.")
```

### tl;dr

- Encountered `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` when receiving a response to a very simple call
- Issue only happened in Safari in production enviornment
- While debugging, we removed one piece of the stack at a time and identified that removing nginx would solve the problem
- The request was a POST, but had no information in the request body, so the body was ignored
- I found a comment on a StackOverflow question that mentioned *reading* the POST request's body has some sort of impact on nginx's request buffer
- Simply assigning the request body to a variable (thus reading the buffer) solved the issue

After all this, I'm just wondering *why* this happens. What is it about not reading the request body that could cause this error? Why only nginx? Why only Safari?

I'm hoping the StackOverflow community can help me explain this one! It was a lot of fun to solve. I also made a short [presentation](http://slides.com/jamiecounsell/233) to share with some coworkers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what version of nginx. If it has not been updated for a few months, It could be this closed issue:

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/959

> Previously, the stream's window was kept zero in order to prevent a
>   client from sending the request body before it was requested (see
>   887cca40ba6a for details). Until such initial window was acknowledged
>   all requests with data were rejected (see 0aa07850922f for details).
>   That approach revealed a number of problems: Some clients (notably MS
>   IE/Edge, Safari, iOS applications) show an error or even crash if a
>   stream is rejected; This requires at least one RTT for every request
>   with body before the client receives window update and able to send
>   data. To overcome these problems the new directive
>   "http2_body_preread_size" is introduced. It sets the initial window
>   and configures a special per stream preread buffer that is used to
>   save all incoming data before the body is requested and processed.

my guess is creating the reference keeps that buffer open after the settings ack goes back and forth.

Try upgrading nginx, since this patch is merged. If you upgrade and still have the issue, this is a regression and I'd open a new nginx ticket.

Comment: Interesting. It has not been updated in a few months. This might just be it! I'm working on a proof of concept for the bug, so I'll see if I can isolate it to the nginx version.